# Apache ignite persistence is not persisting

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I set up 2 nodes with persistence enabled on my custom region.

```
    <dataStorageConfiguration>
        <defaultDataRegionConfiguration
            name="Default_Region"
            initialSize="104857600"/> <!-- 100*1024*1024 -->

        <dataRegionConfigurations>
            <dataRegionConfiguration
                name="My_Region"
                initialSize="104857600"
                persistenceEnabled="true" 
                metricsEnabled="true" />
        </dataRegionConfigurations>
    </dataStorageConfiguration>
```

My cache client configuration looks like this

```
new CacheClientConfiguration(
    "MY_SCHEMA",
    new QueryEntity(object, typeof(object)))
{
    SqlSchema = "MY_SCHEMA",
    CacheMode = CacheMode.Replicated,
    DataRegionName = "My_Region",
};
```

I started both nodes, and activated the cluster. I created a bunch of tables with some data.

Then, I turned off node 2, and I checked that my replicated tables (and data) are still there, but the partitioned tables are missing.

I turned off node 1 then brought it back up, but now everything is gone.

Is this the expected behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: What's your partitioned caches configuration?

Comment: I use the same cache configuration for everything. I am supposed to configure the cache using SQL; I added the data_region to all of the table definitions and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have your partitioned caches defined inside `My_Region` region, otherwise they will be created under the default region that does not have persistence enabled.

Comment: I am using SQL first approach and I did not put the region on the table definition. It works fine now after I added it to all of the tables. Thx